# C++ #include function not being to find header file in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, include-path

I used this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main 0 {

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting these errors:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath
cannot open source file iostream
cannot open source file SDL/SDL.h
```

Comment: Are these Intellisense errors in the editor, or actual build errors? The answer to that question is what decides what configuration file to edit.

Comment: Doesn't the error include a link, explaining how to fix it?